# How to search database within less time

Tags: java, database, algorithm, search

I have near about 1 million entries in my database table and
I need to use some logic by which I can search within minimum time,
is there any algorithms or logic by which i can get result within less time.
I tried sorting table alphabetically but till it is taking much more time.
If you have any algorithm or logic then please suggest code in Java.

Comment: Which kind of database?

Comment: What is `10 lakh entries`? What is your code so far? What is the current performance?

Comment: How about indexing that table?! Taking it to the java layer doesn't seem to be a good approach, IMO.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order for us to help you, we need more details. Can you give an example of a query you want to make from your table? Perhaps the solution is as simple as adding an appropriate index to the database. However, you should do some benchmarks before optimizing.

Comment: Do have proper indexes on the table? Rather than optimizing it in JAVA I would suggest that you optimize the query which fetches the records from DB? Are your database statistics updated?

Comment: I would recommend to use the numeric value of a lakh (100,000) in your question as this is understood all over the world.
However as for your question. One million records is not a lot. Did you try using an index on the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to ad in [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) to your database table.
If you tell what database you are using, people can give more specific help.

Comment: i am using mysql database

Answer (score 0):

It dosent matter how much records you have as long as your databse is properly normalised and is having proper index. Having said that, the only difference that will make is how you are using indexes. You cannot do much in java, but your db and its design will play a significant role.